# As for all the tags input with the specified attribute to set, for example, attribute checked = false?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Put tags input type = "radio" with its attribute data-group:

```
<input type="radio" id="id1" data-group="group1">
<input type="radio" id="id2" data-group="group1"><br>
<input type="radio" id="id3" data-group="group2">
<input type="radio" id="id4" data-group="group2"><br>
```

How at all elements of input `type="radio"`, which is data-group "group1", set the `checked=false`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the attribute selector:

```
$('input[type="radio"][data-group="group1"]').prop('checked', false);
```

Or `filter()`:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('group') == 'group1';
}).prop('checked', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to group radio buttons is to use the `name` attribute; the browser will then group them together for you, unchecking others when you check another member of the same group. That's the purpose of `input[type=radio]`:

```html
<input type="radio" id="id1" name="group1">
<input type="radio" id="id2" name="group1"><br>
<input type="radio" id="id3" name="group2">
<input type="radio" id="id4" name="group2"><br>
```

And if you wanted to make all of the `name="group1"` ones unchecked, then:

```
$("input[type=radio][name=group1]").prop("checked", false);
```

---

But if you want to use your current structure, and you're asking how to set them all unchecked, then you can use an attribute selector:

```
$("input[type=radio][data-group=group1]").prop("checked", false);
```